# Get value of index using PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql

I have one database that has two tables.

One table (Table A) has 3 columns:

```
   idpms serial NOT NULL,
   iduser integer NOT NULL,
   iduser2 integer NOT NULL,
```

And the other (Table B) 3 columns

```
  idmessage serial NOT NULL,
  idpms integer NOT NULL,
  text character varying(255),
```

I'm using Java to manage my database.

First, table A is updated with the values of user one and user two.
With the `idpms` values generated when I insert this data, Table B is updated with `idpms` and `text`

I have two questions:

1. How can I retrieve the value of `idpms` after inserting data in Table A?
2. In Java, can I somehow extract the `idpms` and cast it to an int?

Comment: Q1 :Yes. Q2 :Yes. Serial is just `autoincrementing integer`

Comment: Thanks but I've searched for the commands and can't find them

Comment: There is no special command just use SQL it is your database column

Comment: SELECT idpms FROM TABLE Table A?

Comment: If you want to get the value after insert yes. If you want to get value before insert then [This article](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/datatypes/serial) discusses about it I hope you get what you want

Comment: "SELECT idpms FROM TABLE Table A?": this is not possible, how can you know which record to take if you don't have the key... the last record could be inserted concurrently by another user. AFAIK it is "mandatory" to use a KeyHolder in PostgreSQL...

Comment: @AmitD Sorry but was unable to come here sooner. Don't you want to answer with your last comment so I can accept the answer?

Comment: @Favolas Added as answer thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1 :Yes. 
Q2 :Yes.

Serial is just `autoincrementing integer`

There is no special command to get the value after insert you can use sql queries for it. 
If you want to get value before insert then [`This article`](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/datatypes/serial) discusses about it I hope you get what you want

Comment: Thanks. This helped me more that I was asking

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into t (iduser, iduser2) values (1,2)
returning idpms
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a KeyHolder object.

Assuming you are using Spring to perform database operations:

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.KeyHolder;
// stuff...

    KeyHolder generatedKeyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();

    // Execute the update
    namedJdbcTemplate.update(sqlQuery, params, generatedKeyHolder);

    // Retrieve the map of ALL the autoincremented fields in the table
    // Just get the desired one by field name
    Integer idpms = (Integer) generatedKeyHolder.getKeys().get("idpms");

    // use idbpms as parameter for your next query...
```

hope that helps